# Ошибка в marionettejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette.js

При подключении шаблона с помощью TWIG получаю ошибку

> TypeError: Marionette.$ is not a function (Requirejs:900)

в чем может быть проблема?

```
var Sidebar = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "/views/main/sidebar.twig",
    initialize: function() {}
});
```

Пример кода. Подскажите варианты работы twig + marionette

Comment: Очевидно же, вы забыли подключить jQuery перед Marionette. Twig тут совсем не при чем. Ковыряйте клиентский код.

Comment: Очевидно, я не забывал подключить jquery, пробелма точно не в этом.